# Number of possible combinations in which ordering doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to figure this out the other day, but failed to arrive at a formula. It seems like a simple problem, though. Forgive me if my use of terminology sounds off, I have never had any formal mathematical training.

If I have 5 different colored balls, and can match-up 3 at a time, how many different matchings are there?

And generally, if I have m different colored balls and I can choose n at a time, how many different matchings are there? What formula can I use to arrive at this number?

These being balls, a permutation like red-green-blue would be equivalent to green-blue-red, blue-red-green, green-red-blue, red-blue-green, and blue-green-red. (I thought this step could be solved by simply dividing by n!, where n is the number of balls allowed at one time.)

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia on combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations)

Comment: You sound like you are pretty close. You want to start by considering the number of ways to choose three colors from 5 (with permutations, but without choosing the same ball twice) this means that  you'll do something like 5*4*3, because you have 5 possibilities for the first, then 4 for the second, etc. this is $m!/(m-n)!$ (in this case $5!/2!$), and then you were right, the last step is to divide by the number of permutations of $n$ elements, $n$ being the number of balls you are choosing.

Comment: For 5 and 3, is the answer 10? Then you're simply looking for the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{5}{3}$ (or $\binom{m}{n}$ in your general case); this is the number of [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is worthwhile to work out small examples "by hand." The numbers $5$ and $3$ are small enough that we can simply list carefully and count. But in this answer, we look at the problem more or less in general.

I will change notation on you a little.  Suppose that we have $n$ different objects. Let $k$ be an integer such that $0 \le k \le n$.  We want to count the number of different of ways to **choose** $k$ objects from these $n$, where order does not matter. Thus, in your example, $n=5$ and $k=3$.

There are many different symbols for this number.  The one most commonly used by mathematicians is $\binom{n}{k}$.  In the schools, and on the keyboards of scientific calculators, the number of ways of choosing $r$ objects from $n$ is denoted by ${}_n\text{C}_r$. There are many other notations. Anything with so many names must be important!

Let's practice a bit.  How many ways are there to choose $3$ colours from $5$? Answer: $\binom{5}{3}$.  How many ways are there to choose a $5$-card hand from a standard $52$-card deck? Answer: $\binom{52}{5}$.  How many $8$-bit strings are there, where a bit is $0$ or $1$, which have exactly $3$ $1$'s?  Answer: $\binom{8}{3}$.  This is because an $8$-bit string with $3$ $1$'s is completely determined once we *choose* the $3$ places where a $1$ will go.

Our answers have not been fully informative!  In many applications, we need to produce an explicit number.  Most scientific calculators have a key for evaluating $\binom{n}{k}$, aka ${}_n\text{C}_k$.  But that's not a satisfying solution.

We give a detailed analysis of how to compute $\binom{16}{5}$, the number of ways 
to choose $5$ objects from $16$.  We are using explicit numbers for the sake of concreteness.  However, the *method* that we will use is perfectly general.

So imagine that we have $16$ different letters, and we want to choose $5$ of them. By definition, the number of ways to do this is $\binom{16}{5}$.

We ask a quite **different** question. How many $5$-letter **"words"** are there, with all the letters different? 
We will count the number of such words in **two different ways**. When we are counting words, the order of letters matters.

**First way**: The first letter can be chosen in $16$ ways.  For *each* such choice, there are $15$ ways to choose the second letter.  So there are $(16)(15)$ $2$-letter words.  For *each* way of writing down the first two letters, there are $14$ ways to choose the third letter, for a total of $(16)(15)(14)$ $3$-letter words.  Similarly, there are $(16)(15)(14)(13)$ $4$-letter words, and therefore $(16)(15)(14)(13)(12)$ $5$-letter words.
To summarize:
$$ \text{There are}\qquad (16)(15)(14)(13)(12) \qquad \text{$5$-letter words.}$$

**Second way**: Let us first of all choose *which letters* will be used to make our $5$ letter word. This can be done in $\binom{16}{5}$ ways. Now for *each* choice of $5$ letters, there are $(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)$ ways of lining them up in a row to make a $5$-letter word. It follows that:
$$ \text{There are}\qquad \binom{16}{5}[(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)] \qquad \text{$5$-letter words.}$$

The two ways of counting must give the same answer. It follows that
$$\binom{16}{5}[(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)]=(16)(15)(14)(13)(12),$$
and therefore
$$\binom{16}{5}=\frac{(16)(15)(14)(13)(12)}{(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)}.$$

**Exactly** The same reasoning shows that in general
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(k)(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(1)}\qquad\qquad \text{(Equation $1$)} $$

We can now use the general method to compute the $\binom{5}{3}$ of your question, though of course for such small numbers we could just list and count:
$$\binom{5}{3}=\frac{(5)(4)(3)}{(3)(2)(1)}=10.$$

**Comment**: Equivalently, we have the formula 
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \qquad\qquad \text{(Equation $2$)}$$
Equation $2$ can be obtained by multiplying "top" and "bottom" in Equation $1$ by $(n-k)!$.  Equation $2$ is more compact than Equation $1$, but less pleasant from the point of view of calculation.

For much more information, please look at the Wikipedia article on [Binomial Coefficients.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: i did do most of that work on a piece of paper while waiting in an airport yesterday, but i wasn't sure if i'd missed anything. thank you for your thoughtful answer. i can now confidently proceed.

Comment: So the long waits are to give us time to do mathematics. Very thoughtful.